# Linear regression: Best way of shrinking parameter estimates to mitigate multiple testing issues

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, multiple-comparisons, regularization

Suppose I calibrate $N$ linear regression equations $(j=1,...,N)$, where $N$ is large (at least 100). The $j$th equation is:

$\boldsymbol{Y}_{j}=\boldsymbol{X}\boldsymbol{\beta }_{j}+\boldsymbol{\epsilon }_{j}$

Where $\boldsymbol{Y}_{j}$, and $\boldsymbol{\epsilon}_{j}$ are length-$n$ vectors and $\boldsymbol{\beta }_{j}$ is a length-$m$ parameter vector, whose first element is $\beta_{0,j}$. Notice the $n×m$ design matrix, $\boldsymbol{X}$, is the same for all regression equations.

After running each model, I have $N$ estimates of the intercept. That is, $\hat{\beta}_{0,1}$ for the first equation, $\hat{\beta}_{0,2}$ for the second, ..., and $\hat{\beta}_{0,N}$ for the $N$th. Some of these estimated intercepts will be large even if the true value is close to 0. What is the best way of 'shrinking' these estimated intercepts to account for this multiple testing problem? Note I'm *not* performing hypothesis testing. But it's clear that the highest estimated intercept is likely to 'biased' just by virtue of being the largest sample estimate, where the 50th percentile estimate is much less likely to be biased... I am looking for a way to mitigate this problem.

I'm aware of L1 and L2 penalized regressions, but I know they result in biased parameter estimates. I also need the same 'penalty' to be applied to all $N$ regression equations to account for this phenomenon.

There is a great deal of work in multiple testing when $p>>N$, but I'm not sure of multiple testing adjustments that can be applied to the above. Thanks.

Comment: This is not a multiple testing problem.  Looking at the literature on multiple testing will only be distracting and likely of little help.  Is there a problem with using a mixed model in your application?

Comment: I think it would be a problem. If m is 5 and N is 500 (N = the number of groups), we will need to estimate 2500 slope coefficients plus 500 separate 'effects' for each group, equaling 3000 parameters and therefore enormous multicollinearity.

Comment: The point of a mixed model is that it *doesn't* require one parameter for each member of a group: it only needs to estimate the variance of that group.  Note, please, that this is the first indication you have given of the size of $m$ you might be interested in.  Since that's important, you ought to include it in your post.

Comment: Yes, but the required output are the estimated intercepts. This is the purpose of the experiment. I indicated that N is at least 100 and this number of parameters estimated in a single model which seems much too high to be feasible.

Comment: You can't have unbiasedness and shrinkage at the same time.  In order for an estimator to be unbiased, it has to have a substantial chance of being too large.

Comment: Thank you. I know that under the standard assumptions, parameter estimates will be unbiased if no shrinkage is used. However, intuitively, it seems to me (which could be wrong), if you estimate N equations simultaneously (N>100), inference on the jth intercept may be able to be improved from observing the results of the other (N-1) intercepts. E.g. it seems obvious that the highest estimated intercept is more likely to be overestimated than underestimated once all N models have been calibrated, but I don't know how to quantify this, or if my intuition is wrong.